# Matching a string only if it is not in <script> or <a> tags

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

I'm working on a browser plugin that replaces all instances of "someString" (as defined by a complicated regex) with `<a href="http://domain.com/$1">$1</a>`. This generally works ok just doing a global replace on the body's innerHTML. However it breaks the page when it finds (and replaces) the "someString" inside `<script>` tags (i.e. as a JS variable or other JS reference). It also breaks if "someString" is already part of an anchor.

So basically I want to do a global replace on all instances of "someString" unless it falls inside a `<script></script>` or `<a></a>` tag set.

Essentially what I have now is:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
body = body.replace(/(someString)/gi, '<a href="http://domain.com/$1">$1</a>');
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = body;
```

But obviously that's not good enough. I've been struggling for a couple hours now and reading all of the answers here (including the many adamant ones that insist regex should not be used with HTML), so I'm open to suggestions on how to do this.  I'd prefer using straight JS, but can use jQuery if necessary.

**Edit - Sample HTML**:

```
<body>
  someString
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var someString = 'blah';
  console.log(someString);
  </script>
  <a href="someString.html">someString</a>
</body>
```

In that case, only the very first instance of "someString" should be replaced.

Comment: Why the regex tag? As you already admit, it's not a job for regular expressions.

Comment: "someString" is defined by a complicated regex which I need to be able to do the match. There's no way I can get around that piece of it. Potentially the traversal/parent node type can be gleaned without using a regex, but I don't have a choice as far as the actual string matching goes.

Comment: Do you only wish to replace this within text on the page?

Comment: @Orbling - yes, only within text on the page.

Comment: @Jeff - Yes, I realize regex isn't the best way to go overall, but as stated above I definitely require it for the specifics of matching the string. Once I have a match I could theoretically determine what the parent node is using some other means, but I've had problems getting that to work with only a string match / offset to work from.

Comment: @dosboy: Or you could use a non-regex solution to find all strings not inside of `<script>` tags, then use the "someString" regex afterwards.

Comment: @Brian - could you give me an example (as an Answer perhaps)? I've tried using the jQuery .not() method and :not() selector, but I am still unable to get the results I'm looking for.

Comment: @dosboy: I'd be more apt to just Google javascript HTML parsers.  Though really, my tendency would be to just make any sort of task that required html parsing be done server-side.  I suppose if you're trying to make a javascript-based browser plug-in that might not be practical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see if it meets your needs (tested in IE 8 and Chrome).

```
<script src="jquery-1.4.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
  var pattern = /(someString)/gi;
  var replacement = "<a href=\"http://domain.com/$1\">$1</a>";

  $(function() {
    $("body :not(a,script)")
      .contents()
      .filter(function() { 
        return this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.search(pattern) != -1;
      })
      .each(function() {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        span.innerHTML = "&nbsp;" + $.trim(this.nodeValue.replace(pattern, replacement));
        this.parentNode.insertBefore(span, this);
        this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
      });
  });
</script>
```

The code uses jQuery to find all the text nodes within the document's `<body>`that are not in `<anchor>` or `<script>` blocks, and contain the search pattern.  Once those are found, a span is injected containing the target node's modified content, and the old text node is removed.

The only issue I saw was that IE 8 handles text nodes containing only whitespace differently than Chrome, so sometimes a replacement would lose a leading space, hence the insertion of the non-breaking space before the text containing the regex replacements.

Comment: This works great. The only thing I had to change was `$("body :not(a,script)")` to `$("* :not(a,script)")` in order to account for items inside tags (divs, etc.). Though admittedly my example didn't list this specifically.

Answer (score 2):

Well, You can use XPath with Mozilla (assuming you're writing the plugin for FireFox).  The call is [`document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.evaluate).  Or you can use an XPath library to do it (there are a few out there)...

```
var matches = document.evaluate(
    '//*[not(name() = "a") and not(name() = "script") and contains(., "string")]',
    document,
    null,
    XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE
    null
);
```

Then replace using a callback function:

```
var callback = function(node) {
    var text = node.nodeValue;
    text = text.replace(/(someString)/gi, '<a href="http://domain.com/$1">$1</a>');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = text;
    for (var i = 0, l = div.childNodes.length; i < l; i++) {
        node.parentNode.insertBefore(div.childNodes[i], node);
    }
    node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
};
var nodes = [];
//cache the tree since we want to modify it as we iterate
var node = matches.iterateNext();
while (node) {
    nodes.push(node);
    node = matches.iterateNext();
}
for (var key = 0, length = nodes.length; key < length; key++) {
    node = nodes[key];
    // Check for a Text node
    if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        callback(node);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0, l = node.childNodes.length; i < l; i++) {
            var child = node.childNodes[i];
            if (child.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                callback(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems very promising, but you were right about the replaceChild() call. I get the following error on that line:   `NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.`  Also I had to replace every instance of `match` with `node` (I'm assuming that's what you were going for - otherwise it throws an error on `node.nodeType`).

Comment: @dosboy: I've edited in a solution to both problems (just renaming `match` as `node`.  And it now manually copies the `div`'s children to the dom instead of trying to batch...

Comment: Progress. If I don't make the callbacks but instead just do `console.log(node)` it's outputting the contents of each non-a and non-script node, which is great. But when I put the callbacks back in it outputs the contents of one node (`<title>`), then throws an error on `node = matches.iterateNext();` : `INVALID_STATE_ERR: DOM Exception 11: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable.`. I also tried adding `and not(name() = 'head')` to the xpathExpression but it doesn't seem to make any difference. FYI this is my first foray into XPath, in case you couldn't tell :)

Comment: I also removed `and contains(., "string")` from the xpathExpression since it doesn't seem necessary (and when I dropped my regex into "string" it never returned any matches).

Comment: Ahhh. I see the problem.  It's because we modify the tree and hence invalidate the tree before we can visit it.  I'll edit in a workaround.  As far as the `contains` bit, it is a filter that only returns nodes that have that string somewhere inside.  Otherwise you wind up walking the entire node tree (which isn't the most performant thing to do)...

Comment: When `callback(child);` is called and `child` contains a string that matches the regex, an error is thrown on `node.parentNode.insertBefore(div.childNodes[i], node);` : `NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.`. Also I have to leave the `contains` bit out as I'm not actually searching for a string, but rather a regex, and it seems `contains()` only accepts strings.

Comment: Oh, I also had to remove the 2nd `var` on `for (var i = 0, var l = div.childNodes.length; i < l; i++) {`, change `while (var node = matches.iterateNext()) {
    nodes.push(node);
}` to `var node = matches.iterateNext();
while (node) {
    nodes.push(node);
 node = matches.iterateNext();
}`, and remove `node = matches.iterateNext();` at the end of the loop.

Comment: Ok.  There's a few in there that could be better (JS isn't my strongest language).  As far as the error, I'm not really sure what's going on there...  As far as not using the .contains, make sure you're testing the regex for matching prior to just replacing.  That may be a cause of the issue (that a parent node gets replaced before you hit that node)...

Comment: I'll dig in some more. The syntactical comments were just so that you could clean up your code for future posterity. Really appreciate the help so far. Hopefully this will get me to where I need to be.

Answer (score 1):

I know you don't want to hear this, but this doesn't sound like a job for a regex. Regular expressions don't do negative matches very well before becoming complicated and unreadable.

Perhaps this regex might be close enough though:

```
/>[^<]*(someString)[^<]*</
```

It captures any instance of someString that are inbetween a > and a <.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is if you do use jQuery, you can use the :contains pseudo-selector.

```
$('*:contains(someString)').each(function(i)
{
    var markup = $(this).html();
    // modify markup to insert anchor tag
    $(this).html(markup)
});
```

This will grab any DOM item that contains 'someString' in it's text. I dont think it will traverse `<script>` tags or so you should be good.

Comment: I tried this, but :contains() doesn't support regex... or doesn't support it well enough for the regex that I require anyway.

Comment: What kind of regex are you trying to put in there? You should only need to put the literal someString value in the selector and it sounds like you don't need regex support to match on that.

Comment: `(someString)` is just the example I used in the question. The actual regex (which I inherited and would prefer not to have to reverse-engineer) is `/\$((?:[0-9]+(?=[a-z])|(?![0-9\.\:\_\-]))(?:[a-z0-9]|[\_\.\-\:](?![\.\_\.\-\:]))*[a-z0-9]+)/`. I just left it out of the question so as to avoid adding confusion.

Comment: Oh. I didn't realize that needed to be a regex too. Yeah, your previous findings are right. That wouldnt work in :contains()

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
/(someString)(?![^<]*?(<\/a>|<\/script>))/
```

I didn't test every schenario, but it is basically using a negative lookahead to look for the next opening bracket following ***someString***, and if that bracket is part of an anchor or script closing tag, it does not match.

Your example seems to work in this [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/LG2Bg/), although it certainly doesn't cover all possibilities. In cases where the innerHTML in your `<a></a>` contains tags (like `<b>` or `<span>`), or  the code in your script tags generates html (contains strings with tags in it), you would need something more complex.